# How do you up vote a comment?

Tags: discussion, accessibility

Before I put this in as an accessibility feature request I want to make sure I'm not missing something. How do you up vote a comment? For questions and answers my screen reader reads vote up and vote down graphics but there's nothing like this for comments.

**EDIT**: I can't figure out how to get my screen reader to hover over a specific line of text then read what it finds, looks like this is an accessibility feature request.  [Opened accessibility request here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20108/make-comment-voting-and-comment-flagging-accessible).

Comment: just curious, WHEN A SCREEN READER ENCOUNTERS TEXT IN ALL CAPS, DOES IT YELL AT YOU?

Comment: @Kip, that's just mean, you might have broken his ears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment vote and flag controls are hidden to the left of each comment until you mouse over them, when you do there is an up-arrow icon with a tooltip which reads "this is a great comment."

Answer (score 1):

Simply move your cursor over the comment and two small, faded, silhouetted symbols appear to the left of the comment: an arrow silhouette for up-voting and a flag silhouette for flagging the comment.

A comment that has received up-votes will display a number to the left, indicating how many.  Currently, there is no way to tell how many of your comments have been up-voted, apart from returning to your each comment and viewing those numbers.

Comment: seeing your own comment vote totals is now possible through SEDE or other workarounds. Example: http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/131713/comments?sort=votes&order=desc